# Link Button url count php and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have a function in my wordpress where it behind me facebook tanned number , the more accurate it brings me a number of shares that a post had! I tried to solve the function , more is giving an error and I need help !

Follows function:

```
function ia_fb_count($url_post) {
//Get the transient value from database
$fbcount = get_transient( 'fblcount' );
    if ( empty( $fbcount ) ){
        //If no value stored, get the like count
        $file = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids="$url_post"');
            $jd = json_decode($file);
            $fbcount = number_format($jd->{'likes'});

        // Set the facebook likes transient value for 24 Hours
        set_transient('fblcount', $fbcount, 60*60*24 );
        // Also, return it at the same time
        return $fbcount;
    } else {
        // Transient Value is present, return it
        return $fbcount;
    }
```

}

call the function in my theme like this:

```
<?php
                $url_post = the_permalink(); 
                echo ia_fb_count($url_post);?>
```

could someone help me ?

Comment: could you please specify how does the error look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is suspicious:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids="$url_post"');
```

probably it should be

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids="'.$url_post.'"');
```

For counting Likes, Shares or Comments you can also try third party solution. [Facebook Analytics](http://fa.baldsoft.com/) is free and works fine with WordPress.